# Compactness in trace norm.

Tags: functional-analysis, vector-spaces, compactness, trace

Consider the space of trace-class operators $TC( \mathcal{H} )$ with the trace norm $\vert \vert \cdot \vert \vert_1$.

Does it hold that the unit ball  $ \{ \rho \in TC( \mathcal{H}) \mid   \vert \vert \rho \vert \vert_1 \leq 1 \}$ is compact in the $\vert \vert \cdot \vert \vert_1$-norm topology?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is no. In fact the only Banach spaces in which the unit ball is compact are finite dimensional.

Answer (score 0):

If the Hilbert space in question $\mathcal{H}$ is finite-dimensional then this should be possible by the following Theorem from functional analysis.

The unit ball is compact in a real Norm Linear Space (NLS) iff the space is finite-dimensional.   (1)

i.e. if the Hilbert space  $\mathcal{H}$  is finite-dimensional then $TC\big(\mathcal{H}\big)$ will be a finite-dimensional Banach algebra. Applying (1) you have what you asked for.